# Modifying a data of type "static const int* const" from a member function

Tags: c++, mutable

TLDR Question:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void Modify()
    {
        //How can I modify MyData here 
    }

public:
    static const int* const MyData;
};
```

Lore:

I have a class like this:

```
class Window
{
public:
    const int* GetKeyboard()
    {
        return m_Keyboard;
    }

private:
    const int* const m_Keyboard = 0;
};
```

With this I would access keyboard as `WindowObjectPtr->GetKeyboard()` but I want to access it as `Input::Keyboard`. So I wrote something like this:

```
class Window
{
public:
    const int* GetKeyboard()
    {
        return m_Keyboard;
    }

private:
    const int* const m_Keyboard = 0;
};

const int* Input::Keyboard = 0;

class Application;
class Input
{
    friend class Application;
private:
    static void SetKeyboard(const int* k) { Keyboard = k; }

public:
    static const int* Keyboard;
};

class Application
{
public:
    void Init()
    {
        Input::SetKeyboard(m_Window.GetKeyboard());
    }

private:
    Window m_Window;
};

int main()
{
    Application application;
    application.Init();

    //Input::Keyboard
}
```

The only problem with the above code is that I can do Input::Keyboaord = nullptr;

So I want to change definition of keyboard to `static const int* const Keyboard;` but then `Input::SetKeyboard` cannot set it anymore.

Is there a valid version of something like `mutable static const int* const Keyboard;` ? or a different method of achieving what I am trying to do?

Comment: why is it `const` when you want to modify it?

Comment: I just want to set it once in that function and never modify it again

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes - it's either a constant or is not - you can init constants with a value. If you just want to protect its value you I guess you can wrap it into a "write-once" class which might have a counter and it only allows you to set something once....

Comment: Why is this even a static member? You have classes `Window` and `Application`, etc. All of these can create multiple objects of the given type. What is the point of the `Input` class if all `Input` objects are forced to use the same `Keyboard`? In other words, why is there not a `Input` member in `Application` instead, like there is a `Window`?

Comment: dont adjust your design according to how you want the syntax to look like. If you give up the requirement that it must be accessible via `Input::Keyboard` then the whole problem is gone.

Comment: in other words, frankly, this looks like a self-made issue. " ... but I want to access it as Input::Keyboard."  why do you want this? Its no encapsulation and already `Input::Keyboard()` would be no problem.

Comment: @user17732522 Fair point but I have decided to go with 1 window per application design. And there can only be 1 application.

Comment: even if there can be only 1 application now, what do you gain by ruling out the possibility that there can be 2? You can always create only 1 instance of a class, but you cannot have 2 instances of a singleton or of a static member.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I guess so, but its just that `Input::Keyboard.Read()` looks nicer than `Input::Keyboard().Read()`. Just wanted to see if theres a way to make it possible but if theres not then ill just go with your version

Comment: you can initialize a `const` object once and after that there is no way to modify it

Comment: Overly complicated, don't use pointers if you don't need to. should just be `const int m_Keyboard;` and `int getKeyboard() const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either an object is `const` or it isn't. If it is `const` it must be given a value in its initialization and any attempt at changing it later will cause undefined behavior (if it isn't ill-formed to begin with).

There is no way to make an object `const` after a certain other point in the execution flow.

Of course you can just add a `const` reference to the object and use that whenever you don't intent to modify it for const-correctness:

```
static const int* Keyboard;
static const int* const& cKeyboard = Keyboard;
```

Now `Keyboard` can be used for modification and `cKeyboard` can't (without `const_cast` trickery).

But that all seems like completely avoidable and messy, since you could just have `Keyboard` be a non-static member, have `Application` have a non-static `Input` member and then have all initialization happen in the constructor's initializer lists. Then there wouldn't be a problem with having `Keyboard` be `const`-qualified at all.

Comment: Thank you sensei, appreciate the wisdom. I will use the non-static member approach.

Comment: @JasonLiam I corrected that to "initialization" instead of "initializer". Even without an initializer the variable may still have non-vacuous initialization of course (as in your question). There are also some exceptions where you can actually leave a `const` object's value completely indeterminate, but that can really only happen if the class is badly designed and such an object would be completely unusable.

Comment: *now it is fine.

Comment: "Either an object is const or it isn't. If it is const it must be given a value in its initialization and any attempt at changing it later will cause undefined behavior" - This hasn't generally been true since c++20. And, it isn't true  for the specific example in the question. See [basic.life](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#8)

Comment: @doug Even though transparent replacement practically behaves as if the object was modified, it still technically involves creation of a _new_ object. Also, a static data member is a complete object with static storage duration and therefore replacing it is _not_ allowed if it is `const`-qualified.

Comment: @user17732522 You are absolutely right about the static object being a complete const object and so is not alterable. I missed the static. As for transparent replacement, it's a new object in the same sense that `a=b` causes `a` to be a new object. The old one is gone and the new one has the same name of `a` and pointers/references to it are valid.

Comment: @doug (Built-in) assignment practically looks the same as transparent object replacement, but the point is that it does _not_ involve replacing the object in the abstract description of the language. `a=b` with `=` the built-in assignment operator never creates a new object (except in specific situations involving unions), it only changes the value of an existing object.

Comment: @user17732522 Is there any difference? I don't see any. Transparent replacement has no different impact on the meaning of the name, reference, or pointer to the "new" object. Is there some difference I'm not aware of? I think of assignment as destruction of the prior value and replacement with a new one.

Comment: @doug It implies at least that assignment is not allowed if the current object is outside of its lifetime (e.g. because it had a (pseudo-)destructor called on it or because its lifetime was never started), while transparent replacement would be ok in this case, and obviously there is the `const` object situation in which assignment (i.e. modifying the existing object) is forbidden, while transparent replacement might not be depending on circumstances. There may be other differences I haven't thought of.

Comment: @doug  And in terms of implementation, transparent replacement may imply certain optimization barriers since it allows modifying memory in ways that assignment can't (i.e. `const` objects).

Comment: @user17732522 Interesting. Placement new for transparent replacement is a specified example. I wonder about others such as memcpy. The change to basic.life has raised a lot of questions. Would be nice for the spec to clarify this change.

Answer (score 1):

Many things can be hacked.

For example you can have a constant `static` member which references a `private` non-static member. The private member can be initialized and set later by a friend. The public member can only be used to read:

```
#include<iostream>

struct foo {
        static const int& x_public;
        friend class bar;
    private:
        static int x_private;
};

const int& foo::x_public = foo::x_private;
int foo::x_private = 0;

struct bar {
    bar() {
        foo::x_private = 42;
    }
};

int main() {
    bar b;
    std::cout << foo::x_public;
}
```

Thgouh, I am not really suggesting to use this. I agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74154817/4117728) that you should rather use a non-static member.